# JSP Select Option onchange query DB and show in TextBox same page

Tags: javascript, jsp, jdbc, java-ee-6

In my jsp file am displaying project name as like this.

```
<label for="email">Project Name</label> 
<select name='project_name' class='required input_field' id='project_name'>
<option value=''>-- Select --</option>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
<option value="${row.ProjectId}">${row.ProjectName}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

my problem is , i want to show the client name of the corresponding project in the textbox below the select option.

```
<label for="author">Client Name</label>
<input type='text' name='client_name' id='client_name' class='required input_field' style='width:260px;'>
```

I want this to display onchange of select option.
for that i have to query database. how can i do this..

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `onchange` attribute to your `select` containing:

```
this.form['client_name'].value = this[this.selectedIndex].innerText
```